# CSS Can't remove indentation from a bulleted list

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am trying to remove the indentation and bullets from a bulleted list using CSS. Here is what I am doing:

```
.entry-content ul{
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:0;}
```

The bullet points are removed from the list, but the indentation is not fixed. Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="entry-content">
     <ul class=wp-block-categories wp-block-categories-list">
          <li class="cat-item cat-item-8"><a href="https://xxx/?cat=8">Advice</a>
          </li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

Here is an image before I apply the CSS:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HU8sp.jpg

Here is an image after I apply the CSS:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nB92.jpg

Does anyone know why the indentation isn't being removed? I am doing this in wordpress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in your HTML.

```
<ul class=:wp-block-categories wp-block-categories-list">
```

should be

```
<ul class="wp-block-categories wp-block-categories-list">
```

As for your CSS, one of these is the most likely:

- The `li` may have a `margin` as well. try `.entry-content ul li { margin-left: 0; }`
- Your selector isn't [specific](https://specificity.keegan.st/) enough, try `.entry-content ul.wp-block-categories-list` instead
- Your `ul` may have `margin` instead of `padding` (doubtful)

You can try and diagnose these with DevTools/your browsers inspector, it will show you all of the positions/margins/paddings and everything related to the element's bounding box: [image: screenshot of dev tools]

Answer (score 0):

You likely also need to apply:

```
.entry-content ul li {
  margin-left: -20px;
}
```

The exact amount of margin will differ based on the size of your font, but 20px is the default.

Comment: Why `-20px`? Why not `0`?